# Cos'è un “fallimento doloso"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> Ad ogni omicidio, ad ogni furto, ecco una diecina di lettere anonime sul mio tavolo; ed anche delle liti di famiglia e dei **fallimenti dolosi**, mi scrivono; e degli amori dei carabinieri...

Cercando in parecchi dizionari, ho trovato i significati di "fallimento" e di "doloso", ma non capisco cos'è un "fallimento doloso". Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Come avrai visto, il senso di un evento doloso è che è stato commesso di proposito anziché succedere per conto suo (come potrebbe essere il fallimento di una società i cui affari non vanno bene, mentre qui forse c'è un intento truffaldino). Poi, però, ci vorrebbe più un avvocato che uno che sa bene l'italiano... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viene in aiuto la chiara definizione del vocabolario Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/doloso/):

> **dolóso** agg. [dal lat. dolosus]. – Che è fatto con dolo, cioè con piena coscienza e intenzionalità [...] in senso generico, che è fatto con inganno, fraudolento.

un fallimento è *doloso* quando appunto avviene in modo intenzionale (e con un intento truffaldino)